# Print Query in controller before save()

Tags: model, controllers, query

I am facing trouble to print query while saving data from my controller file.

I am developing a custom module where I am required to save current date and time when form is submitted. The user is not inputting the date.

```
$timeStamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$model->setCreatedTime(Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate(null, $timeStamp ));
$model->save();
```

Here when I print my `$model->getData();` I see created_time value but its not reflecting in DB

Also I tried with below code to print SQL query but it says `Call to a member function printLogQuery() on a non-object`.

```
// For printing the whole SQL with the Collection
var_dump($model->printLogQuery(true));

// For printing only the SQL
var_dump($model->__toString());
```

How can I print INSERT query for above scenario ?

Pls help

Thanks

Comment: have you set `timestamp` as type for 'created_time'

Comment: No, for created_time its DATETIME while for updated_time its TIMESTAMP

Comment: you could always set the `created_time` as set on the mysql side of things by setting `default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` on the column

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the advice in the answer here: [Print INSERT Query in saveAction](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/23885/print-insert-query-in-saveaction/56216#56216)

This will guide you to modify `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::query()` located in `lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php`... this is a core hack but does work for getting to this query.

Using Z-Ray on Zend Server is much easier, you can see all the queries on any given request without modifying any Magento files. You can try it out: http://serverdemo.zend.com/magento/