# Print INSERT Query in saveAction

Tags: database, module, magento-1, model

I have a custom module where my few DB fields are not being saved properly. I can see the values selected in `$model->getData();` but it does not reflects in my Database.

```
try {   

       echo '<pre>';print_r($model->getData());echo '<br>';// shows correct values selected
        $model->save(); 
        echo '<pre>';print_r($model->getData());exit;// shows correct values saved

    }
```

The above code shows me correct values being selected and processed, but not saved in DB.

Is there any way where I can print the INSERT query and check what is caysing the issue ?

Please Help !!!

Thanks.

Comment: try clearing cache

Comment: I am working on localhost

Comment: like mentioned above by  pradeepsanku, clear the cache. Even if the cache is disabled the table definition is still cached.

Comment: Okay, I cleared the cache and still it does not saved properly. Could anyone let me know how to print insert query while saving the `$model`

Comment: please try to specify that are you using a controller in custom module to set the some values in session. Or using anywhere set->session function.

Comment: Delete your table and your core setup in core resource table. create table again and check.

Answer (score 2):

Magento queries run through `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::query()`  located in `lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php`

In the `query` method you can add something like this:

```
if (strpos($sql, 'INSERT') === 0) {
    var_dump($sql);
    var_dump($bind);
}
```

to print all the INSERT queries and data bound to them (for debugging only, of course).

Comment: This is a core hack, and should be done very carefully. But it does work.

Answer (score 2):

This is built-in, but somewhat guarded. Once again, [n98-magerun](http://magerun.net) comes to the rescue:

```
n98 dev:log:db --on
```

Now, you can see all queries with parameters in `var/debug/pdo_mysql.log`.

Answer (score 1):

Using Z-Ray on Zend Server you can see all SQL queries. It trivializes this problem, and you dont have to do any core hacking. You can see it in action: http://serverdemo.zend.com/magento/